# Are SELECT type queries the only type that can be nested?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, subquery

Is it possible to have an non-select query (update, insert, delete) embedded into another query?

Something like (an insert inside a select)

```
A single query:

select such,and,such from .... where .... insert into .... ;
```

Comment: In Postgres, yes using CTEs.  In MySQL, no.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Basic answer

There are [**CTEs** (Common Table Expressions)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) in **Postgres** - like in any major modern RDBMS, That includes [MySQL since version 8.0](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-labs-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes/).
Since version 9.1 Postgres also features [data-modifying CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING), which can be "nested".

Unlike *subqueries* CTEs pose as optimization barriers. The query planner cannot inline trivial commands into the main command or reorder joins among main query and CTEs. The same is possible with subqueries. May be (very) good or (very) bad for performance, it depends.
Either way, CTEs require a bit more overhead than subqueries.

Update: **Postgres 12** can finally [inline plain CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/release-12.html#id-1.11.6.8.5.3.4) in the main query.

#### Details you did not ask for

Your question is very basic, the above is probably enough to answer. But I'll add a bit for advanced users (and a code example to show the syntax).

All CTEs of a query are based off the *same snapshot* of the database. The next CTE can reuse the *output* of previous CTEs (internal temporary tables), but effects on underlying tables are invisible for other CTEs. The sequence of multiple CTEs is arbitrary *unless* something is returned with the `RETURNING` clause for `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` - irrelevant for `SELECT`, since it does not change anything and just reads from the snapshot.

That can have subtle effects with multiple updates that would be affecting the same row. Only *one* update can affect each row. Which one is influenced by the sequence of CTEs.

Try to predict the outcome:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE t (t_id int, txt text);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'baz');

WITH sel AS (SELECT * FROM t)
   , up1 AS (UPDATE t SET txt = txt || '1' WHERE t_id = 1 RETURNING *)
   , up2 AS (UPDATE t SET txt = t.txt || '2'
             FROM   up1
             WHERE  up1.t_id = t.t_id
             RETURNING t.*)
   , ins AS (INSERT INTO t VALUES (4, 'bamm'))
   , up3 AS (UPDATE t SET txt = txt || '3' RETURNING *)
SELECT 'sel' AS source, * FROM sel
UNION ALL
SELECT 'up1' AS source, * FROM up1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'up2' AS source, * FROM up2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'up3' AS source, * FROM up3
UNION ALL
SELECT 't'   AS source, * FROM t;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=787bfe6eab889e67c6e41f592537740b)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/1541)</sub>

Don't be disappointed, I doubt there are many here who could have done it. :)
The gist of it: ***avoid*** conflicting commands in CTEs.

Comment: That conflicting CTEs example melts my brain a bit; I'll take your advice and just avoid anything that begins to resemble it!

Comment: @IMSoP: Took me some time to understand it, even though I built it myself. :)

Comment: Also, note that while CTE terms share the same snapshot, they do *not* execute atomically. It's still entirely possible to have a race condition on a unique index between an `INSERT` in a CTE term and an outer `UPDATE` in the face of concurrent transactions, for example. So writeable CTEs don't provide a magic solution to the upsert problem or other common concurrency issues.