# Results, such as RETURNING, from uncomitted execs?

Tags: c++, postgresql, prepared-statement, libpqxx

With libpqxx, is it possible for one prepared statement that `exec`s but has not yet been `commit`ted to store results in a `result` for use in later prepared statements?

If so, how can this be done?

### Code

I've stripped it down for readability, but this is essentially what I'm trying to do:

```
void prepare_write_parent_table(connection_base &c){
    try
    {
        c.prepare("write_parent_table", 
            "INSERT INTO parent_table (column_1) "
            "SELECT $1 "
            "RETURNING id"
        )
        ("character", pqxx::prepare::treat_string);
    }
    catch (const exception &e)
    {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }
}

string write_parent_table(transaction_base &t, string data){
    try
    {
        result parent_table_result = t.prepared("write_parent_table")(data).exec();
        return parent_table_result[0][0].c_str();

    }
    catch (const exception &e)
    {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
        return "";
    }
}

void prepare_write_child_table(connection_base &c){
    try
    {
        c.prepare("write_child_table", 
            "INSERT INTO child_table (parent_table_id, column_a) "
            "SELECT $1, $2 "
        )
        ("character", pqxx::prepare::treat_string)
        ("character", pqxx::prepare::treat_string);
    }
    catch (const exception &e)
    {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

The `return` from `write_parent_table` is checked to see `if( == "")`.  If it isn't, it proceeds; otherwise, I will `commit` there to let it fail or more preferably cancel the transaction if possible; however, I don't yet know how to do that if it is even possible.

There will always be an uncertain amount of `INSERT`s into `child_table` per `parent_table` `INSERT`.

Comment: `for (result::size_type i=0; i < Results.size(); ++i) other_prepare_object(Results[i]);`  http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/3.1/html/Reference/a00076.html

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Thank you CantChooseUsernames!  So you're saying a result can be returned from an `exec` that hasn't been committed yet?  If so, this is an amazing setup!

Comment: I didn't personally try it but it's worth a shot. Stick that loop into your code and print whatever `Results[i]` is and see.. If `Results.size() > 0` then I say yes. Otherwise no.

Comment: As long as you *prepare* the next query *after* saving the results to a table (or temp table), everything inside the same transaction is visible.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thank you for looking Erwin Brandstetter!  Would you mind clarifying in an answer?  I'm trying to `RETURNING` the `id` from a parent table, to be used in a child table's column referencing the parent, by storing it in a `result` from an `exec`.  After all of the prepared statements are `exec`ed, I then `commit`.  Are you saying that the transaction needs to be broken up, that to get the `RETURNING` value, it must be `commit`ted first?  If so, should I set isolation to `SERIALIZABLE`?  If so, how?  Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: @Gracchus: Please show your code and (relevant parts of) table definitions and your version of Postgres. I suspect all of this can be solved with a single SQL statement using data-modifying CTEs. [Example.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775109/postgresql-multi-insert-returning-with-multiple-columns/22775268#22775268)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify the operation by using a single SQL statement for both inserts using a [**data-modifying CTE**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING). This is much faster than storing intermediary states in the client.

The `INSERT` in the child table only happens if the first `INSERT` in the parent table is successful and returns an `id`:

```
void prepare_write_both_tables(connection_base &c){
    try
    {
       c.prepare("write_both_tables", 
          "WITH p AS ("
             "INSERT INTO parent_table (column_1) "
             "SELECT $1 "
             "RETURNING id) "
          "INSERT INTO child_table (parent_table_id, column_a) "
          "SELECT p.id, $2 "
          "FROM   p"
        )
        ("character", pqxx::prepare::treat_string)
        ("character", pqxx::prepare::treat_string);
    }
    catch (const exception &e)
    {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

[Search for [postgres] & "data-modifying CTE"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D%20%22data-modifying%20CTE%22) for more examples.
Also called "writable CTE" (or "writeable CTE").

#### Multiple children

For a *single* parent and *0 to many* children:

```
void prepare_write_both_tables(connection_base &c){
    try
    {
       c.prepare("write_both_tables", 
          "WITH p AS ("
             "INSERT INTO parent_table (column_1) "
             "SELECT $1 "
             "RETURNING id) "
          "INSERT INTO child_table (parent_table_id, column_a) "
          "SELECT p.id, a "
          "FROM   p, unnest($2::text[]) AS a"
        )
        ("character", pqxx::prepare::treat_string)
        ("character", pqxx::prepare::treat_string);
    }
    catch (const exception &e)
    {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

Where The second parameter is an `array of text` in text representation. Example:

```
{foo,bar,baz}
```

This inserts as many rows as there are elements in the text array. For 0 children pass `NULL` or an empty array `{}`.

Comment: Double-check the C++ syntax. I am an expert with Postgres, but not with C++.

Comment: @Gracchus: I added a version for multiple children.

Comment: This one accepts the *text representation* of an array. Maybe there are more elegant ways to pass an array ...

Comment: @Gracchus: SQL injection is not possible here. The data will only be treated as data in a prepared statement. If the syntax is not valid, you get an exception and everything is rolled back.

Comment: @Gracchus: Why'd you delete the other question? I had a half finished answer in the queue ...

Comment: @Gracchus: Proper questions are *always* welcome. And dba.SE is just fine.