# Do nothing in a trigger procedure

Tags: postgresql, triggers, duplicates, plpgsql, upsert

I got a trouble when a try to execute a trigger. Let's suppose we have 2 tables and I want to copy data from **table A** to **table B** but each table got a **unique constraint**.

```
create table test1 (
 test_name varchar);

create unique index test1_uc on test1 USING btree (test_name);

create table test2 (
test_name2 varchar);

 create unique index test2_uc on test2 USING btree (test_name2);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trig_test()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
  IF pg_trigger_depth() <> 1 THEN
    RETURN NEW;
END IF;
INSERT INTO test2(test_name2)
   VALUES(NEW.test_name2)
ON CONFLICT (test_name2) DO NOTHING;

RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_test
AFTER INSERT
ON test2
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trig_test();

insert into test2 values ('test');
insert into test2 values ('test'); //should do nothing ?
```

But I get this error:

> ```
> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test2_uc"
> DETAIL:  Key (test_name2)=(test) already exists.
> ```

What's wrong with the trigger?

Comment: You need to use `return null` in the trigger. And the trigger **has** to be a `BEFORE` trigger

Comment: Fine for before trigger, but if I do return null I can't do a copy from table 1 to table 2 cf http://rextester.com/LAJB87421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is broken. Source and target are the same in your `INSERT` in the trigger, which is bound to raise a unique violation *every time* (except when inserting NULL) - suppressed by `ON CONFLICT (test_name2) DO NOTHING`, so nothing ever happens in the trigger.

You also forget about the unique constraint in your original `INSERT`. See below.

```
INSERT INTO test2(test_name2)
   VALUES(NEW.test_name2)

...

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_test
AFTER INSERT
ON test2
```

Start with a less confusing setup:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (col1 text UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE test2 (col2 text UNIQUE);
```

And it's more efficient to move [`pg_trigger_depth()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-SESSION-TABLE) to the trigger itself. So this would work, copying rows inserted into `test1` to `test2` (and not the other way), only for the *first* level of trigger depth:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trig_test()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO test2(col2)             -- !!
   VALUES (NEW.col1)                   -- !!
   ON     CONFLICT (col2) DO NOTHING;  -- !!

   RETURN NULL;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I kept it as `AFTER` trigger. Can be a `BEFORE` trigger as well, but there you'd *need* `RETURN NEW;`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_test
AFTER INSERT ON test1                  -- !!
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() < 1)          -- !!
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trig_test();
```

Why `(pg_trigger_depth() < 1)`?

- [How to prevent a PostgreSQL trigger from being fired by another trigger?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103402/how-to-prevent-a-postgresql-trigger-from-being-fired-by-another-trigger/103661#103661)

***Note*** that you trap unique violations in `test2` this way (nothing happens), but unique violations in `test1` would still raise an exception unless you have `ON CONFLICT ... DO NOTHING` there as well. Your test is wishful thinking:

> ```
> insert into test2 values ('test'); //should do nothing ?
> ```

Has to be:

```
INSERT INTO test1 values ('test') ON CONFLICT (col1) DO NOTHING;
```

#### Alternative: Chain two `INSERT` with a CTE

If you have control over `INSERT` commands on `test1`, you can do this instead of the trigger:

```
WITH ins1 AS (
   INSERT INTO test1(col1)
   VALUES ('foo')                  -- your value goes here
   ON CONFLICT (col1) DO NOTHING
   RETURNING *
   )
INSERT INTO test2(col2)
SELECT col1 FROM ins1
ON CONFLICT (col2) DO NOTHING;
```

Related:

- [Insert data in 3 tables at a time using Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561254/insert-data-in-3-tables-at-a-time-using-postgres/20561627#20561627)
- [PostgreSQL multi INSERT...RETURNING with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775109/postgresql-multi-insert-returning-with-multiple-columns/22775268#22775268)