# SQL: Multiple inserctions into the relation table in a many to many relation

Tags: sql, postgresql

Okay, question is simple.

I have a table call predictions. To simplifiy, this table has a primary unique key ID, and a observation_id.

Then I have a table metrics, which saves different metrics for each observation_id.

This is clearly a many to many relation between two tables since one observation_id can have different metrics computed over it, but also each type of metric can be computed for different observation ids.

Thus, I have created a relations table predictionmetrics which links the primary key of prediction table, with the primary key of metrics table.

My problem comes when inserting multiple elements at the same time. IMPORTANTLY, the table predictions is written at some other points since metric computation must be done separated from prediction generator, i.e., I cannot write three tables at the same time.

So assume we have 10 observations_id written into table predictions with its IDs_pred, and we compute a metric for these 10 observations. I want to insert the 10 metrics into the metrics table and retrieve the associated IDS_met of these inserctions, so that I can then write into the table predictions metrics IDs_pred and IDs_met.

My problem is that If I use the following queries:

```
INSERT into metrics (whatever) VALUES (%s)  RETURNING id
```

where I insert_bulk to insert all metrics in a single query, RETURNING id only returns the last inserted id.

So then when executing

```
INSERT into predictionmetrics (prediction_id, metric_id) VALUES (%s, %s)
```

it only insert one value instead of 10.

For what I have read in SQL there is no way to insert and retrieve ID from multiple elements at a time, something I see as a huge limitation because then we cannot efficiently handle inserctions into related tables.

Any solution?. A colleague mentioned to use UUID to generate unique IDs for metrics table and insert them, rather than relying on the SQL engine to do it by itself.

Comment: I think your colleague's suggestion to use UUIDs for generating unique IDs before insertion is indeed a practical approach to handle this scenario in PostgreSQL. By generating the UUIDs in advance, you can maintain control over the association between your predictions and metrics tables without relying on the sequential IDs generated by the database. This method allows you to insert multiple records into your metrics table and immediately use those UUIDs to associate records in your predictionmetrics join table without the ambiguity of trying to match which IDs were generated for which record.

Comment: I don't know what this `insert_bulk` is, but `RETURNING` definitely returns multiple results. "in SQL there is no way to insert and retrieve ID from multiple elements at a time" this is demonstrably not true https://dbfiddle.uk/TveYEm4x

Comment: If you have only a *single* process that inserts the rows, you may pass the `id` assignment into the client.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment, if you have only a single process there is no need to use sequences and you may assign the `id` a simple as `max(id) + n`. Alternatively you may pre-fetch the `nextval` in the required count and use them in inserts.

But the `returning` clause *contrary your claim* may do it es well using  [Data-Modifying Statements in WITH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

I use a simplified setup with one parent (`t`) and one child table (`c`):

```
create table t (id serial not null, observation_id int not null);
create table c (id serial not null, t_id int not null, value int not null);
```

Here only a warm up how to retrieve the assigned `id` along with the natural key of the table (`observation_id`) while inserting multiple rows

```
WITH ins_parent AS (
   insert into t (observation_id) values (10),(20),(42)
   returning  id, observation_id 
   )
select id, observation_id from ins_parent; 

id|observation_id|
--+--------------+
1 |            10|
2 |            20|
3 |            42|
```

In the full example we will use the  data-modifying CTE as a lookup to get the *surrogate key* of the parent.

Example of an insert of three observation along with four measured values. A generalization on an additional lookup to a `measure_id` should be simple.

```
WITH ins_parent AS (
   insert into t (observation_id) values (10),(20),(42)
   returning  id, observation_id 
   )
insert into c (t_id, value)
select ins_parent.id t_id, x.value from (values 
(10, 102),(10,211),(20,125),(42,101)
) x(observation_id, value)
join ins_parent on x.observation_id = ins_parent.observation_id;
```

The query below shows the inserted data

```
select t.id, t.observation_id, c.id, c.value from t
join c on c.t_id = t.id;

id|observation_id|id|value|
--+--------------+--+-----+
4 |            10| 1|  102|
4 |            10| 2|  211|
5 |            20| 3|  125|
6 |            42| 4|  101|
```

Similar answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22775268/4808122)