# PostgreSQL: Update function return boolean

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, boolean, sql-returning

Is the function below good?

```
CREATE FUNCTION password_set(bigint, char) RETURNS boolean AS $$
   UPDATE users SET password = $2 WHERE id = $1 RETURNING TRUE;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

It returns `TRUE` when `UPDATE` sets `password` but `NULL` (instead of `FALSE`) when `UPDATE` doesn't set `password`.

I think that will work for all intents and purposes, but do you think that's OK?

If not, how would you change the function to return `FALSE` (instead of `NULL`) if the `UPDATE` doesn't set `password`?

Comment: Is `id` UNIQUE or can there be multiple affected rows? Also, your version of Postgres?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You do **not** want to use the data type <strike>**`char`**</strike>. That's short for `character(1)` and **completely wrong** for passing a "password" text. Any string would be truncated to the first character. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html)

> The notations `varchar(n)` and **`char(n)`** are aliases for `character varying(n)` and `character(n)`, respectively. `character` without length
> specifier is equivalent to **`character(1)`**.

Bold emphasis mine.

Next, what's wrong with a function returning `TRUE` or `NULL`?

If you actually need to return `TRUE` / `FALSE`, your idea using a [data-modifying CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22750328/939860) works. However, the code is misleading. You make it seem like `TRUE` in the final `SELECT` would matter, but it doesn't:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION password_set(bigint, text)  -- not char!
  RETURNS boolean
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
   WITH u AS (
      UPDATE users
      SET    password = $2
      WHERE  id = $1
      RETURNING 1
      )
   SELECT EXISTS (SELECT FROM u);
$func$;
```

[`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) only considers if a row is returned. It's irrelevant whether you write `NULL` or `FALSE` or `TRUE` or `*` or nothing at all or whatever. The function returning `TRUE` only tells us, the `UPDATE` returned one or more rows.

**Alternative** would be a **PL/pgSQL** function using the [special variable **`FOUND`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) (improved with [input from posz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071530/postgresql-update-function-return-boolean/23072862?noredirect=1#comment35274864_23072862):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION password_set(bigint, text)
  RETURNS boolean
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   UPDATE users SET password = $2 WHERE id = $1;
   RETURN FOUND;
END
$func$;
```

Comment: Maybe `RETURN FOUND` would be more clearer as `FOUND` is already a `BOOLEAN` *variable*.

Answer (score 1):

If you just add `SETOF` before `boolean`, then instead of 1 row with a `NULL` cell, the function will return 0 rows.

Otherwise, you could try:

```
CREATE FUNCTION password_set(bigint, char) RETURNS boolean AS $$
   WITH u AS (UPDATE users SET password = $2 WHERE id = $1 RETURNING TRUE)
   SELECT EXISTS (SELECT TRUE FROM u);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Comment: There is no SETOF in your sample.