# Having update inside array()

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to accomplish something like:

```
select array(update table set value = '' where condition returning another_value)
```

This one seems to give a syntaxerror. I imagine I could wrap the inner part inside a function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
WITH Result AS (
  update table set value = '' where condition returning another_value
)
SELECT array(SELECT * FROM Result)
```

Seems a little clunky to me, but I couldn't simplify it any further without running into syntax errors...

Comment: Data-modifying statements are not allowed in simple subqueries. [That's only possible with CTEs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749253/are-select-type-queries-the-only-type-that-can-be-nested/22750328#22750328).