# Using DEFAULT in an INSERT/UPDATE statement vs CASE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column with a default value set. An `UPDATE` statement like this will work as expected:

```
UPDATE some_table SET
  some_column = DEFAULT
WHERE id = 1;
```

However, when I try to use a condition like this, i get a syntax error near `DEFAULT`:

```
UPDATE some_table SET
  some_column = CASE
    WHEN TRUE THEN DEFAULT
    ELSE 'foo'
  END
WHERE id = 1;
```

Is there a valid way to achieve the expected result?

Comment: Your options are an expression or the magic word `DEFAULT`. `DEFAULT` can't appear in arbitrary positions inside of an expression.

Comment: No. Just like you can't do `order by case when true then asc else desc end`. It's part of the syntax, not a function

Comment: So there is no way to overcome this? I know I can explicitly state the value instead of using `DEFAULT` but it's unelegant. I can also use a stored procedure with its control structures but isn't that a little overkill for a simple update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that. You can use an expression there **or** the `DEFAULT` keyword.

```
SET { column = { expression | DEFAULT } | ... }
```

However, you can split your query into 2 updates:

```
UPDATE some_table
SET some_column = DEFAULT
WHERE id = 1 AND some_condition;

UPDATE some_table
SET some_column = 'foo'
WHERE id = 1 AND NOT some_condition;
```

This will do the desired changes. If you really want to do it in one query, you can use [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)s:

```
WITH upd1 AS (
  UPDATE some_table
  SET some_column = DEFAULT
  WHERE id = 1 AND some_condition
  RETURNING *
),
upd2 AS (
  UPDATE some_table
  SET some_column = 'foo'
  WHERE id = 1
  RETURNING *
)
SELECT * FROM upd1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM upd2
```

**Note**: the `AND NOT some_condition` skipped intentionally. The last CTE can work exactly as the `ELSE` branch in the `CASE` expression, because if you use multiple data modifying CTEs, [maximum one of them can affect every row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749253/are-select-type-queries-the-only-type-that-can-be-nested) within a table.