# Trigger seems to be fired after transaction, not after command/statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, transactions, common-table-expression

I have two tables `foo` and `bar`, and an `after trigger` on `foo` which changes something on `bar` table.

```
create table foo(id serial primary key, _key char(128) not null);
create table bar(id bigserial primary key, _key_p char(256) not null);
```

So when I have a transaction, such as invoking a function like below, the trigger is fired after the transaction, not the statement or related dml action.
The trigger for `foo` table:

```
create or replace function foo_trg_func()returns trigger as $$
declare k_p char(256);begin
k_p:=(select res from prepare_pa(new.key));
insert into bar(_key_p) values(k_p);--insert it to the bar
end $$ language plpgsql;
--
create trigger foo_trg
after insert on foo
for each row execute procedure foo_trg_func();
```

The sample function/transaction

```
create or replace function `bas`(int,character(128))returns int as $$
-- some commands
with res as (select res as "d" from c_key($1,$2)),
-- attemp to insert into foo and expect the insertion to bar too
ins as (insert into foo(_key) select d from res returning 1)  --line[5]
-- check the effect of the foo_trg
select _key_p from bar,res where _key_p=res.d;    --line[7]

$$ language sql
```

The trigger is called and data is inserted to the `bar` table by `foo` trigger, but after the function call, and I cannot get the result of trigger insert at line 7.
How may I do this now?

*I also have to mention that it's possible to mark the trigger as instead or before, but it will cause many changes, so I wondered if it's possible to do with `after` triggers.*

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `ins as (insert into foo(_key) select d from res returning id)`?

Comment: Yes sir, typo mistake, thank you. @Denis

Comment: @Denis: The added `RETURNING` clause serves no purpose, CTE `ins` is not referenced. The edit was a misunderstanding, orthogonal to the problem.

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Not yet sir, if I want to forget the triggers and do the things just as you mentioned, I must code for months and re-code again. currently I select the results after I invoke the function, but wonder why it's not possible with a sucha perfect db!?

Answer (score 0):

#### Why?

First, you must be aware that you are running a *single* statement (with multiple CTEs.)

Common table expressions of a single query see the **same snapshot** of the database. Each CTE (and the final command) can reuse output from previous CTEs (internal temporary tables), but effects on underlying tables are **invisible**. Your final `SELECT` cannot see any effects of the CTE `ins` on underlying tables.

A separate `SELECT` afterwards (even in the same transaction, can be in the same function) will see the effects.

See:

- [Are SELECT type queries the only type that can be nested?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749253/are-select-type-queries-the-only-type-that-can-be-nested/22750328#22750328)

#### Solution for your case

You have two conflicting requirements:

1. You want to use changed rows form an underlying table (not available from the `RETURNING` clause of the CTE, because those are side effects from a trigger on another table). But the changes are **not visible inside** the same statement.
2. You want combine that with values returned from a CTE with the `RETURNING` clause, but those are **not visible outside** the statement with CTEs.

Resolve this by materializing the derived table from a CTE in a `TEMPORARY TABLE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bas (int, text)
  RETURNS SETOF int
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   CREATE TEMP TABLE foo_tmp (LIKE foo) ON COMMIT DROP;

   WITH ins AS (
      INSERT INTO foo(_key)
      SELECT res FROM c_key($1,$2) f
      RETURNING foo.*
      )
   INSERT INTO foo_tmp
   SELECT * FROM ins;

   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT b._key_p
   FROM   bar b
   JOIN   foo_tmp f ON b._key_p = f._key;
END
$func$;
```

*Alternatively*, you could remove the trigger and do the `INSERT` manually (if that's a single point of entry).

#### Asides

- You almost certainly don't want `character(128)`. Use `varchar(128)`, or just `varchar` or `text`:
- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)
- No backticks for identifiers (`` `res` ``). Looks like spillover from MySQL, which is nonsense in Postgres. [Use double-quotes instead](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) (only where you must).
- Your trigger function can be much simpler / cheaper:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo_trg_func()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO bar(_key_p)
   SELECT res FROM prepare_pa(NEW.key);
END
$func$;
```

Or simpler yet if `prepare_pa()` returns a single value.

Comment: I think his effect was more along the lines of: one of the CTEs was yielding no rows, so the last statement was returning nothing.

Comment: @Denis: I don't think so. Actually, I think there was a misunderstanding. I'll comment above.