# How can I aggregate and collapse rows in a database table using SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression, duplicates

I have a table with example data as shown below.

```
word       | last_seen  | first_seen | count
-----------|------------|------------|------
definition | 2014-09-08 | 2012-01-02 | 15
definition | 2014-10-11 | 2013-05-12 | 35
attribute  | 2013-07-23 | 2010-06-29 | 22
```

I'm wanting to to an in-place aggregation of the data, hopefully just using SQL, where the data for repeated words is such that I end up with `MAX(last_seen)`, `MIN(first_seen)`, and `SUM(count)`.

```
word       | last_seen  | first_seen | count
-----------|------------|------------|------
definition | 2014-10-11 | 2012-01-02 | 50
attribute  | 2013-07-23 | 2010-06-29 | 22
```

I know I can see the results of the aggregation with the following:

```
SELECT 
  word, 
  MAX(last_seen) AS last_seen, 
  MIN(first_seen) AS first_seen, 
  SUM(count) AS count 
FROM 
  words 
GROUP BY word;
```

However, I don't just want to see the resulting aggregation... I want to actually update the `words` table, replacing the rows that have duplicate `word` column entries with the aggregated data.

Comment: I dont see why your code isnt giving you what you want. can you elaborate on `I just don't know how to update the words table in-place with the results`

Comment: You have at least two statements, one to update, the other to delete the now irrelevant record.

Comment: Are you sure you want to update the existing table, or do you just want a view with the aggregated data?  What if it changes again?

Comment: You can do a combined select, update and delete in one query using the with clause: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there is no "Edit in place" in Postgresql (or any other traditional RDBMS that I can think of). Instead:

1. Take the results of your query and dump them into a temp table: `CREATE TEMP TABLE <temptable> AS <Your Query> WITH DATA`
2. Delete out everything in your `word` table: `TRUNCATE word;` *<--This is the scary part so make sure you are cool with your query before truncating.*
3. Insert the records in your temp table into the now empty `word` table: `INSERT INTO word SELECT * FROM <temptable>;`
4. Optionally: Drop your temp table `DROP TABLE <temptable>;` (being a temp table it will drop automagically when you end your session, but I'm a fan of being explicit)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you ***can*** do that in a single statement using data-modifying CTEs:

```
WITH del AS (
   DELETE FROM words w
   WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM   words w1
      WHERE  w1.word = w.word
      AND    w1.ctid <> w.ctid
     )
   RETURNING *
   )
INSERT INTO words(word, last_seen, first_seen, count)
SELECT word, MAX(last_seen), MIN(first_seen), SUM(count)
FROM   del
GROUP  BY word;
```

Should be rather efficient, too.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d0a0f/1)

About `ctid`:

- [In-order sequence generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500013/in-order-sequence-generation/17503095#17503095)

About CTEs:

- [Are SELECT type queries the only type that can be nested?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749253/are-select-type-queries-the-only-type-that-can-be-nested/22750328#22750328)